# Indexing system vs raw DMBS connection

Tags: mysql, index, solr

I have created a new dataset that has 11,000,000+ rows with 4 pivot tables in MySQL.  The tables are not that deep, only 6 - 12 cols per.

My question is I've set up the Lucene Apache SOLR to index the data, and it work's great for searching .. BUT

I haven't noticed a dramatic load time in searches.  If I run a raw SQL command, the difference between the two is negligible.  At what point is it more beneficial to use a indexing engine vs scripting a raw query yourself?

Now granted I have the ability to set "weight" and all that via SOLR .. But my impression was that I would have dramatically reduced overhead on the server ...  Is it just that my dataset isn't large enough / complicated enough to illicit these finding?  Other than the obvious advantages being weight, rank and sort/filter -- What is the overhead advantage of using a indexing system such as SOLR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At what point is it more beneficial to use a indexing engine vs scripting a raw query yourself?

An abstracted layer for indexing is never going to be *better* or more performant than a correctly architected database structure. The purpose of it is instead to be a tool to make it *easier* for someone who is inexperienced with implementing a correctly architected structure.

> I haven't noticed a dramatic load time in searches. If I run a raw SQL command, the difference between the two is negligible.

We'd have to see the table structure, the index definitions, the query you ran, and ideally it's query plan (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) to be able to specifically comment on how efficiently it's operating. But generally if you're just doing straight `SELECT`s against a table, they'll run *relatively* well, and when indexed properly should run efficiently.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain what they disagree with or are confused about?

Comment: I'd like to second that notion -- Obviously my OP was downvoted by the same person as well.  I have searched the interwebs for this specific idea and came up short of a direct answer.  I felt it was too ambiguous to put on S.O.  So I posted it here hoping for some good will.  Thank you for your answer J.D.  It's a straight `SELECT` with 4 `JOIN`s  I don't feel it necessary to burden the board with such a simple data set (5 tables using a single PK in the main table).  As I suspected, raw, efficiently built queries are my best bet.  I only tried SOLR to see if I could shave MS off to no avail.

Comment: @J.D. I'm come to a conclusion that some people downvote because of a bad day and I don't think the downvoter will see your comment, better let it go.